# Chance light intensity in a pwm pin using LDR using Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, led, pwm

[image]I am using proteus and Arduino software to simulate my circuit. What I need to do, is to have an LDR in my Arduino uno. When light intensity increases in my LDR, I need another LED which is connected to a PWM pin to react to this change in light intensity. The more light LDR detects I need my LED to get dimmer and vice versa.
I have uploaded my circuit picture. The potential probe that I have connected to LDR works fine, the more light there is, the higher voltage it has (ranged from 0 to 5v) but on the other side, my LED does not work properly. If LDR detects little light. my LED is turned on, surprisingly with no current passing the ammeter, when light intensity is less than some threshold, my LED starts blinking! again, no current passing through the ammeter! and the voltmeter always varies between 0 and 4.9 (voltmeter on my LED), it never has a value between 0 and 4.9, it seems it acts digitally, while I have used analogWrite. By the way, I mention again that I need my LED pin to have PWM.This is my code in Arduino:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(A0,INPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
Serial.println(sensorValue);


analogWrite(10,sensorValue/4);

delay(200);       
}
```

By the way, I know the way I have coded, it means that LED follows the torch, and the more light intensity LDR feels, the brighter LED gets, I need it to be vice versa but I also did not know how to use it.
And finally, a minor question:
what does the  Serial.println() function do? I mean it must print it's content somewhere, but where? This feature would be useful for debugging, but I don't know how to see its printed value. I should also say that my code is a modified version of analogReadSerial example.
Thanks.

Comment: upvote for asking about the serial.print() ... it prints to the serial port ... you can view the output using the serial monitor in the arduino IDE ... you can also use any other serial terminal program such as PuTTY

Comment: @jsotola Hello.Thanks for your comment. It worked about printing issue, however I still have my main issue. I don't know how to upvote your comment, it only has a flag icon on it.

Comment: @jsotola By the way, I don't know why it only worked once. I mean it pooped up for the first time, but later times, when I tried to print it, didn't pop up :|

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of simulation. I'll bet if you did it with real hardware your results would be very very different.

Comment: @Majenko How is that possible? You mean it's IDE's fault and my board and code is perfectly ok?

Comment: I mean simulation is only an approximation, and Arduino simulation is notoriously bad.

Comment: It'd be better to use oscilloscope for watching PWM signal on the LED pin. It's hard to measure something even in real life if you don't have meter that supports measuring duty cycle or so.